# Better code for creating object and updating its property from XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have XML input with multiple Invoice elements. I create invoice objects from these elements. Based on the position of invoice element we need to assign sequence number and find corresponding message from a different element – StatusMsg.

I have following C# code in .Net 4.0. It works fine and reasonably readable. Is there any better code in terms of `performance` without sacrificing `readability`?

**CODE**

```
// Create a collection of invoice elements
var invoiceEntities = xDoc.Descendants("Invoice")
              .Select(x => new Invoice
               {
                  Vendor = x.Element("Vendor") == null ? String.Empty : x.Element("Vendor").Value.Trim(),
                  Amount = x.Element("Amount") == null ? String.Empty : x.Element("Amount").Value.Trim()
               });

List<Invoice> invoices = invoiceEntities.ToList();

//Iterate all entities for finding corresponding message element and update the entity's Message

int count = 0;
foreach (Invoice entity in invoices)
{
           count++;

           //Dynamic XPath statement
           string messagePath = @"Status/StatusMsg/StatusDetail/Sequence[text()=" + count.ToString() + "]/../Message";
           var statusDetails = xDoc.XPathSelectElements(messagePath).FirstOrDefault();
           if (statusDetails != null)
           {
               entity.Message = statusDetails.Value;
               entity.Sequence = count;
           }

  }
```

**Entity**

```
public class Invoice
{
    public string Vendor { get; set; }
    public string Amount { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public int Sequence { get; set; }
}
```

**XML**

```
  XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse(@"  
          <Status>
                <StatusMsg>
                    <StatusType>INVOICE</StatusType>
                    <StatusCode>READYPAY</StatusCode>
                    <StatusTimestamp>2013-03-19T21:20:54Z</StatusTimestamp>

                    <StatusDetail>
                        <Sequence test=""K"">  2  </Sequence>
                        <Message>STL MESSAGE </Message>
                    </StatusDetail>

                    <StatusDetail>
                        <Sequence test=""1"">  1  </Sequence>
                        <Message>AKP MESSAGE</Message>
                    </StatusDetail>

                    <StatusDetail>
                        <Sequence> 1 </Sequence>
                        <Message>CC</Message>
                    </StatusDetail>

                </StatusMsg>
                <Invoices> 

                    <Invoice>
                        <Vendor>
                         AKP LLC
                        </Vendor>
                        <Amount>
                         100
                        </Amount>
                    </Invoice>

                    <Invoice>
                        <Vendor>
                         STL Inc
                        </Vendor>
                        <Amount>
                         20950
                        </Amount>
                    </Invoice>

                </Invoices>
            </Status>
           ");
```

**References**:

1. [Generate c# object code and assign values to its properties from an xml document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10562315/generate-c-sharp-object-code-and-assign-values-to-its-properties-from-an-xml-doc)
2. [Use Annotations to Transform LINQ to XML Trees in an XSLT Style - Eric White](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2007/07/30/how-to-use-annotations-to-transform-linq-to-xml-trees-in-an-xslt-style.aspx)
3. [Advantages of XSLT or Linq to XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066362/advantages-of-xslt-or-linq-to-xml)

Comment: Consider `XmlSerializer.Deserialize()`. MSDN link - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/tz8csy73.aspx

Comment: unless he can re-structure the xml, de-serialize wont do him that much good.  He has no defined link between StatusDetail and Invoice other than Invoice Sequence, which seems rather fickle.  I recommend re-structuring that if you have the option.  Of course, you could de-serialize it and then use the Index of the Invoice List against the Sequence of the individual StatusDetail entries...but that seems like a lot of work for very little, if any, gain.  More memory intensive as well....

Answer (score 1):

About the only thing I could really recommend is to store the `StatusDetail` nodes in a List as well, just grab the whole lot of them once, then you can reference the list via a second linq statement to filter the sequences.  This might be slower in the end than simply building and re-using XPath strings though.

```
var Details = xDoc.Descendants("StatusDetail").ToList();

...

var statusDetail = Details.Where(a => a.Sequence == count).FirstOrDefault();
```

as a picky development point, its usually recommended to use `String.Format` when doing oddly concantenated strings like that...something about the back-code being more efficient...

```
string messagePath = String.Format("Status/StatusMsg/StatusDetail/Sequence[text()={0}]/../Message", count);
```

Another option, you are already building an anonymous type, there's no real reason that you cannot build count into the Invoice option.  That at the very least saves you from having to separately declare and maintain count in the loop.

```
int count = 1;

var invoiceEntities = xDoc.Descendants("Invoice")
          .Select(x => new Invoice
           {
              Vendor = x.Element("Vendor") == null ? String.Empty : x.Element("Vendor").Value.Trim(),
              Amount = x.Element("Vendor") == null ? String.Empty : x.Element("Amount").Value.Trim(),
              Index = count++
           });//yes that works, I tested it because even I wasn't sure, but Index is correct and different for each element
```